# Como llamar a una librería que has guardado en un directorio y no directamente en la raíz

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando un programa y para ello he tenido que bajarme una librería, `ivport`. La cosa es que yo ahora mismo descargué directamente desde github a la carpeta "general" de mi programa dicha librería y allí mismo guardé mi script `proyecto.py`.

Mi programa funciona perfectamente pero ahora me gustaría saber cómo se hace para estructurar mi carpeta "general" y por ejemplo tener una que se llame librerías y dentro una carpeta para cada librería, pues voy a tener que importar otras como por ejemplo `opencv`. Es decir quiero estructurarlo de la siguiente manera,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto mi pregunta es, cómo se hace para llamar dicha librería pues según vi se hace con un punto para concatenar carpetas pero me da error.

```
from librerias.ivport import ivport
```

> ImportError: No module named librerias.ivport

También probé pero me da error de sintaxis:

```
from librerias/ivport import ivport
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Existe fichero `__init__.py` en librerias para que Python lo considere módulo? Lo mismo con librerias/ivport.

Comment: lo único que tengo es un `init_ivport.py`, ahora investigaré cómo crear ese archivo y que poner. Gracias (Gràcies)

Comment: de res :) Simplemente debes poner un archivo de nombre exactamente `__init__.py` y sin nada dentro. De este modo Python sabe que en este directorio "tiene que mirar"

Comment: No entiendo, ¿nada dentro? Entonces cómo sabe que debe buscar en `librerias/ivport`, me sigue dando el mismo error

Answer (score 2):

Descargar una librería Python desde Git y copiarla a una carpeta no es en general la forma correcta de instalarla. El proceso de instalación, según las librerías, puede ser algo tan simple como bajarse un archivo .py y dejarlo en la carpeta apropiada (más sobre esto despúes), o más complejo como tener que bajarse además todas las dependencias (librerías necesarias para que la librería nueva funcione), o mucho más complejo, como tener que descargar partes escritas en C (pues muchas extensiones Python están escritas en este lenguaje por eficiencia), compilarlas (para lo que necesitarás un compilador de C, como `gcc` o Visual Studio) e instalar en las carpetas apropiadas los binarios en ensamblador y el resto de scripts python, normalmente por separado. Si tienes suerte, es posible que alguien haya hecho el trabajo de compilarlo en un operativo idéntico al tuyo y en este caso puedas bajarte las versiones precompiladas, lo que te evita tener que compilarlas tú y puedes entonces instalarlas sin `gcc`)

Como ves, el proceso puede ser complejo. Por eso existe una herramienta diseñada específicamente para esto, denominada `pip`. Un simple `pip install paquete` hará todo lo anterior si el paquete está disponible en [pypi](https://pypi.org/), que es la forma estándar de distribuir los paquetes python. Pero si no está disponible allí, también puedes instalar directamente desde un repositorio git: `pip install url_repositorio`

En cualquier caso, `pip` intentará descargar antes una versión binaria para tu operativo, y si esa no existe, descargará la versión fuente para tratar de compilarla (lo que podría dar problemas si no tienes las herramientas de desarrollo apropiadas). Instalará también todas las dependencias necesarias, y dejará cada cosa *en su sitio*.

Y eso nos lleva a ¿cuál es ese sitio donde deben copiarse las cosas? `pip` lo hace en una carpeta que depende de qué intérprete python se esté usando. Por defecto, estarás usando el intérprete de sistema, por lo que lo intentará copiar a las carpetas de sistema. Esto no es en general buena idea. Para empezar en esas carpetas sólo puede escribir el administrador, pero además instalar librerías de terceros a nivel de sistema puede sobreescribir otras versiones que ya estuvieran instaladas de las mismas, y causar que programas python que dependían de ellas dejen de funcionar.

Y por eso existe `virtualenv`, inicialmente un script instalable aparte, y actualmente un módulo que viene ya con la biblioteca estándar python, que te permite crear una carpeta y dento de ella toda una instalación local de Python más las librerías que necesites en un momento dado. Esta instalación local no afecta a la de sistema, por lo que puedes tener varias (una carpeta para cada una), cada una de ellas con las bibliotecas y herramientas necesarias para un proyecto concreto, en las versiones concretas que requiera ese proyecto, y "activar" una u otra instalación según necesites.

Usando virtualenv el proceso podría ser:

```
$ cd tu_carpeta_de_proyecto
$ python -m venv paquetes   # Crea una sub-carpeta llamada paquetes, con un python local
(Si el anterior no funciona prueba virtualenv paquetes)
$ source ./paquetes/bin/activate   # Activa ese entorno (en linux)
$ which python                 # Comprueba que el intérprete a usar ahora será el local
$ which pip                    # Y lo mismo con pip
$ pip install loquesea         # Instala localmente el paquete loquesea desde pypi
```

En Windows la forma de "activar" el paquete es diferente. Tienes que poner `.\paquetes\Scripts\activate.bat` si estás en una consola cmd.

Otra opción es usar una distribución alternativa de Python como la de [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), que tiene sus propios mecanismos para crear entornos virtuales (`conda create entorno`, `conda activate entorno`) y para instalar paquetes (`conda install paquete`). En paquetes complejos con muchas dependencias y partes en diferentes lenguajes (como los usados en *data science*), conda te da la ventaja de que ya los tiene precompilados para los principales operativos (Windows, Linux, OSX).

Comment: Muchas gracias, conocía pip pero no sabía que hacer cuando no está en este directamente. En cuanto a lo del escritorio virtual, es algo que ya tenía en cuenta, pero esto es una `raspberry pi` con un objetivo específico por lo tanto solo se usará para un proyecto concreto y por lo tanto "creo" puedo instalar directamente en el sistema.